# KEMP Load Balance with Oracle Virtualbox VMs

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, load-balancing, virtualbox

I have KEMP setup as a VM in Virtualbox using their provided image. I also have a CentOS VM on the same physical machine. I'm having trouble getting KEMP to recognize the CentOS VM. KEMP is accessible through the local network, as is the CentOS VM. However, adding the CentOS VM to KEMP as a real server continually gives a status of 'Down' and will not allow connections through the KEMP virtual service.

Adding the physical machine's IP to KEMP will allow connections to the physical machine, so I assume KEMP is setup properly in that sense. The only issue is having KEMP allow the CentOS VM to be connected.

Both VMs use the physical machine's network adapter in bridged mode. Maybe this is causing the issue? The physical machine has 4 network adapters total, not sure if I can use them to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, in case any future searchers have this issue:

The initial setup was fine. Apparently, KEMP will not show a healthy status (or allow connections to any page on the server) unless the server has an index.php or index.html file. Super simple, but I personally had no idea. Add an index and you're golden.